# tmux pane log file location

Tags: tmux

Where does tmux store the current pan contents? Is there any log file? I want to be able to search this log file programmatically via a script. I know we can search manually by tmux inbuilt commands. Thats not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not save it to disk. You will need to use tmux commands.